# Firefox completely enable webcam and microphone without prompting

Tags: firefox, webcam, microphone

Like many browsers, Firefox performs a check when an application requests webcam or microphone access. If the site is already on a whitelist or the user agrees, then access is granted.

I'm wondering if it's possible to completely disable this check, so access is always granted. Ideally, I'd like to set this option through a config file... but I'm not opposed to more invasive options like compiling my own firefox with some collection of flags that disable the permission check behavior.

The use case here is troubleshooting and working around bugs in software where a website / web application doesn't realize that it's been granted permission to use the webcam and microphone. I'm not intending to use a horribly insecure / arguably misconfigured Firefox outside of a pretty narrow use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via profile settings, no need to flags or to compile your own.

Set `media.navigator.permission.disabled` to `True` and you will not be prompted anymore.